# .NET Core 6 Windows auth and Active Directory group based permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, active-directory, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

How does one get user data (user name and surname, and user groups) from company's Active Directory (WinServer) in dotnet core 6?

I have Identity package installed, but the app needs to work with Windows Auth and Active Directory groups for permissions.

How

Comment: Have you read this?: [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, but i failed. Could not get AD groups from WinServer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some more googling I found way it works for me

> 1. Create a new class which would extend the IClaimsTransformation.
>
>    ```
>    public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation  
>    {  
>        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)  
>        {  
>            var wi = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;  
>            if (wi.Groups != null)  
>            {  
>                foreach (var group in wi.Groups) //-- Getting all the AD groups that user belongs to---  
>                    {  
>                        try  
>                        {  
>                            var claim = new Claim(wi.RoleClaimType, group.Value);  
>                            wi.AddClaim(claim);                          
>                        }  
>                        catch (Exception ex)  
>                        {  
>                           throw ex;  
>                        }  
>                     }  
>             }              
>              return Task.FromResult(principal);  
>        }  
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Add Singleton to builder in Program.cs
>
>    ```
>    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
>    ```
> 3. Use [Authorize(Roles = "YourGroupName")] in your controllers

For single link:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "YourGroupName")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
   return View();
}
```

For whole controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "YourGroupName")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
}
```

Guide from:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authorization-using-windows-active-directory-groups-in-net-core-2-razor-pages/

Comment: Yes, this is a good way. Note that hardcoding your group name is not a best practice. You can make it a constant at least, but that won't allow you to use different groups for lower environments versus production. What I do is this:
-create a set of constants for the different roles (possibly only one if you only have one group per environment
-put the allowable group(s) in appsettings
-inject an appsettings class into the claims transformer
-claims transformer has logic to map appsettings groups to constants and puts the constants in the claims
-the Authorize tag references the constants

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In production i made separate class with Static Details, where i put all my groups i need. Sadly my knowledge level is not enough for injecting, but when i learn this topic, ill return to your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

for connecting to AD

```
   using(  PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN")){}
```

put your group in "YourDomain"

for  geting information from AD use this code

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

by this code you will get All user information

if you want login or Edit User information from Active Directory i will send you the full code

Comment: Thank you for your code! I do not need to edit user, just get user and user groups. And if i need to restrict access by active directory groups? I have, for example, user, supervisor and admin. I have Areas in my MVC app. Also, i am using Microsoft Identity for accounts for now, i need to save some additional info. There are some external libraries as Facebook, Twitter, etc, but no Active Directory.