# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using Windows authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I am looking for some help implementing Windows authentication / authorization in .NET Core 6. I can't find any good videos on the topic and plan to make one once I finish this project.

I found the following document to [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

and implemented this code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services
       .AddAuthorization(options =>
              {
                  options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
              });
```

Now that this is implemented, I can't seem to find where I would specify which users are allowed to access the website. I would like this setup so there is no user login, however as long as they are using a windows account that is part of the right group they can access the parts of the website that are setup for that group.

As of right now the only thing I need to secure is a Web API, however in the future there will be a front end to secure as well (possibly Blazor).

Can anybody point me to a tutorial on implementing this or tell me how to set this up?

Comment: I'm curious why there is still Windows Authentication nowadays? Why not to use free Azure AD or other cloud IAM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 6 Windows auth and Active Directory group based permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448845/net-core-6-windows-auth-and-active-directory-group-based-permissions)

Comment: Nothing is free in Azure. You basically need a provider (Azure AD, AuthO) that will generate jwt tokens for you. If you want full control, look into IdentityServer.

Comment: IdentityServer may be the way to go. I thought there was a built in method for this, but learning IdentityServer wouldn't be a bad idea for me in any case.

Comment: @GHDevOps, Azure AD has free tier.

Comment: @TomGordon, IdentityServer is not free anymore.

Comment: If it isn't free, where do you buy it? I think it is still free. I see nothing about purchase on their website. Azure AD would most likely work the same way as in house AD (LDAP etc.)

Comment: Almost every app I work with in the IT industry has the ability to use AD authentication. You would think there would be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody point me to a tutorial on implementing this or tell me how to set this up?

According to the description, I suggest you could create a claim transfer class to query the role and add it to the claims when using the windows authentication.

Then you could directly use the Authorize Roles attribute to allow just specific group use to that controller.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var re = ci.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid || x.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid).ToList();
        foreach (var item in re)
        {
            string account = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(item.Value).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
            var roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, account);
            ci.AddClaim(roleClaim);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Inject it inside the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

Usage:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "NT AUTHORITY\\Local account and member of Administrators group")]
    [HttpPost("WindowsAuthTest")]
    public IActionResult WindowsAuthTest()
```